# Message mapping to elliptic curve in BLS signature

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, group-theory, bls-signature

In the BLS signature the subgroup $G$ of elliptic curve constructed with point $P$ with prime order $q$ by $G=\langle P\rangle $. The $h(x)$ is a hash function. The point $S$  is map (image) of $h(m)$ on elliptic curve. The signature is multiplying the private key in the point $S$.

Is the point $S$, also in $G$ and a multiple of point $P$ such as $kP$?

Comment: "The point $S$ is a map..." What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether the pairing is a [type 1 pairing or some other type of pairing](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15928/in-bilinear-pairings-what-is-the-difference-between-type-2-and-type-3). In a type 1 pairing, $S$ is a multiple of $P$. In any other type of pairing, $S$ is not a multiple of $P$.